# Report Toolbar in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, performancepoint

I have a SharePoint farm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SharePoint 2010. In my production environment, my SSRS report within a Performance Point dashboard renders with the "old school" toolbar, which is the desired result. Sadly, my other three environments render the same report with a different toolbar.

Note also that the the SQL Server version is 08R2 SP1 on #1 and 08RS SP1 CU4 on #2.

Can anyone tell me what it takes to render dashboard reports with toolbar #1 instead of toolbar #2?

[image: Toolbar #1]

[image: Toolbar #2]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably most definitely something introduced with the SQL Server cumulative updates.

However, just to be sure, can you check the version number of SharePoint you have installed? PPS' integration is quite basic, it just creates an IFrame with a generated URL to the SSRS ReportView of the needed report, with all the parameters passed through the querystring. So my guess is moreso to do with SQL versions.

Also check the version of the SharePoint AddIn installed.